# How to insert text box values from C# into Oracle Database

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, winforms

Okay I'm new to all of this and am struggling to insert `TextBox` values (user input) in Windows Form Application and storing these into an Oracle Database Table.

**C# code:**

```
string oradb = "DATA SOURCE = larry.uopnet.plymouth.ac.uk:1521/orcl.fost.plymouth.ac.uk;PERSIST SECURITY INFO = True;USER ID = xxxxxxxxxx;password = xxxxxxxxx";

OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(oradb);
con.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into USER.Client VALUES (txtBoxClientName, txtBoxClientCity, txtBoxClientCountry, txtBoxClientNumber, txtBoxClientURL, comboClientStatus)";

int rowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (rowsUpdated == 0)
    MessageBox.Show("Please fill in required fields");
else
    MessageBox.Show("Client has been added");
con.Dispose();
```

This error appears at the `int rowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` line - An unhandled exception of type `Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException` occurred in Oracle.DataAccess.dll

**Trigger code in Oracle:**

```
create or replace TRIGGER trg_client_ClientID
BEFORE INSERT ON client FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :NEW.ClientID := seq_client_ClientID.nextval;
END;
```

Comment: Check your connection string first, then I also suggest you providing error details, inner exceptions and stack trace regarding `OracleException` there.

Comment: Okay I've done some playing around but still no luck. I am 100% sure my connection string is correct (if I alter it, an error appears at con.Open instead) It's either my CommandText or my exception catching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to fix it with the help of adding in the OracleException and ArgumentException and by using the Parameter code from Elkhan - here is my altered and working code:

```
    private void btnClientSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string oradb = "DATA SOURCE = larry.uopnet.plymouth.ac.uk:1521/orcl.fost.plymouth.ac.uk;PERSIST SECURITY INFO = True;USER ID = xxxxxxxxx;password = xxxxxxxx";
        string insertquery = "Insert into Client VALUES (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7)";


        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(oradb);
        con.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = insertquery;
        try
        {

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("1", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("2", OracleDbType.Varchar2, txtBoxClientName.Text, ParameterDirection.Input));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("3", OracleDbType.Varchar2, txtBoxClientCity.Text, ParameterDirection.Input));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("4", OracleDbType.Varchar2, txtBoxClientCountry.Text, ParameterDirection.Input));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("5", OracleDbType.Varchar2, txtBoxClientNumber.Text, ParameterDirection.Input));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("6", OracleDbType.Varchar2, txtBoxClientURL.Text, ParameterDirection.Input));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("7", OracleDbType.Varchar2, comboClientStatus.Text, ParameterDirection.Input));

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Client has been added");
            con.Close();
            Close();
        }
        catch (OracleException e1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e1.Message);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException e2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e2.Message);
        }
        finally
        {                
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: **"cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("1", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue));"** parameter with name "1" is not return value, and you just not binded parameter value. it must be like that:

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, string.Empty, ParameterDirection.Input));

Comment: I thought it needs to be return value as that field is automatically generated by Oracle as it's the Primary Key and in my case the Client ID column. From researching I found out that ODP.NET only works via the order of the table's columns rather than by name when it comes to Insert queries.

Answer (score 0):

like that:

```
    cmd.CommandText = "Insert into USER.Client VALUES (:param_txtBoxClientName, :param_txtBoxClientCity, :param_txtBoxClientCountry, :param_txtBoxClientNumber, :param_txtBoxClientURL, :param_comboClientStatus)";

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_txtBoxClientName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, txtBoxClientName.Text, ParameterDirection.Input));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_txtBoxClientCity", OracleDbType.Varchar2, txtBoxClientCity.Text, ParameterDirection.Input));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_txtBoxClientNumber", OracleDbType.Varchar2, txtBoxClientNumber.Text, ParameterDirection.Input));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_txtBoxClientURL", OracleDbType.Varchar2, txtBoxClientURL.Text, ParameterDirection.Input));
```

Comment: I've put this code into effect and put in 2 catch statements for OracleException and ArgumentException. I then get the error returned saying "Invalid Parameter binding. Parameter name: ClientName" I'm not really sure how to fix it from there